# <script> tags keep getting stripped out on save by super admin in Joomla 1.6

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, joomla

I have already loaded the jQuery into head section via template manger. I know it is loading properly because it's loading a `.php` page and image into an element..

```
$("#divid").load("thefolder/thepage.php"); // - works great.
```

The problem is that inside of the articles there's an issue when saving... It keeps stripping out the script tags. From my research I see there were past problems with this and Joomla. It seems it got fixed with newer releases by having the filters. But what about 1.6?

I think I have disabled all the text editors and text filters for every user and group! 
And still, when I save under super admin with no text editor it saves and reloads the page with no script tags!

`div` tags save ok though.

Comment: Did you try to setup the editor plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go directly to your database and edit the article contents within the fields there.

Find jos_content and change the "introtext" and "fulltext" fields.

Comment: Ok well... A lot of people and now including myself have made the following mistake or something similar. If your having problems like this then it is most likely a permissions issue that can be set in Extention Manger - Manage - Check the box - Click options in the top right corner.

Comment: and change the blacklist option for your group as well as making sure that your plugin has been enabled in plugin manager. And finally as always be sure that your text editor plugin settings support the change under Plugin Manager.